# Internal Server Error when using event hooks in Eve

Tags: python, flask, eve

I am trying to get an event when ever I do a POST request. This is the code:

```
from eve import Eve

def before_insert(response):
print 'About to return artists'

app = Eve(settings='settings.py')
app.on_insert += before_insert

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

I have no code in the settings file to accommodate the events - just standard stuff that works fine when I remove the line:
    app.on_insert += before_insert

When I do a POST I get:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
<title>500 Internal Server Error</title>
<h1>Internal Server Error</h1>
<p>The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request.  Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application.</p>
```

when I do GET on the resource I get the data but the POST has not been added...

Wassup??

Comment: Can you post your settings.py file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your callback function has a wrong signature. Try the following.

```
from eve import Eve

def before_insert(resource_name, items):
    print 'About to return artists'

app = Eve(settings='settings.py')
app.on_insert += before_insert

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

In any case, try running the app with `DEBUG = True` in your settings file, or run it with `app.run(debug=True)`, so you can get a hint on what the actual problem is.

Comment: Hi nicola, that fixed it - Thanks! Don't know how I got that wrong...  Great framework - thanks for that as well